# How to use scrollEdgeAppearance in iOS 15?

Tags: ios, uikit, uinavigationbar

Here's Apple's document of **scrollEdgeAppearance** for UINavigationBar:

> When a navigation controller contains a navigation bar and a scroll
> view, part of the scroll view’s content appears underneath the
> navigation bar. If the edge of the scrolled content reaches that bar,
> UIKit applies the appearance settings in this property.
>
> If the value of this property is nil, UIKit uses the settings found in the
> standardAppearance property, modified to use a transparent background.
> If no navigation controller manages your navigation bar, UIKit ignores
> this property and uses the standard appearance of the navigation bar.
>
> When running on apps that use iOS 14 or earlier, this property applies
> to navigation bars with large titles. In iOS 15, this property applies
> to all navigation bars.

Here's my demo. I embed ViewController into a UINavigationController, then drag a UITableView and set it as the subview of ViewController's view. I set the following appearance properties to UINavigationBar:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let redAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        redAppearance.backgroundColor = .red
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = redAppearance
        
        let greenAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        greenAppearance.backgroundColor = .green
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = greenAppearance
    }
}
```

I thought the initial navigation bar should be red, and it should turn green when I scroll the table view. But the truth is it's the other way around.

[image: Initial State]
[image: Scrolling State]

I did some search and most people just set **standardAppearance** and **scrollEdgeAppearance** to the same instance, or set one of them to be nil, so I'm quite confused about these two properties in iOS 15.

Answer (score 6):

You have understood perfectly but backward.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = greenAppearance
```

means the nav bar will be green only when the scrollable view is scrolled *all the way down*. That is what you see in your first screen shot.

As soon as you scroll up a little bit, the nav bar starts adopting its standard appearance, which is red. That is what you see in your second screen shot.

Comment: I think what makes me confused is this sentence: "If the edge of the scrolled content reaches that bar, UIKit applies the appearance settings in this property." From what I understand, when I scroll up the scrolled content should be in the "reaching nav bar" state as it is now under the bar. -_-|||

Comment: Well stop listening to whatever you're reading and listen to me. And reality.

Comment: lol. Okay. Thanks! BTW, I find that if I remove the table view, the navigation bar is still green. This is weird as there's no scroll view and scrollEdgeAppearance still takes effect.

Comment: If you have nothing that scrolls, you shouldn't be giving your nav bar any scroll edge appearance.

Answer (score 0):

`scrollEdgeAppearance` is applied when the edge of the scrollable content reaches the nav bar so what you're seeing is correct. Many people set both `scrollEdgeAppearance` and `standardAppearance` to the same since they want the behavior to be no different when the user scrolls but your implementation is certainly a valid use case.

Comment: I think it depends on how you understand "the scrollable content reaches the nav bar". In my 2nd screenshot, table view is scrolled up and some cells are under/covered by the nav bar, i.e., the scrollable content reaches the nav bar.